# 504 timeout on wget command when executed from shell script

Tags: timeout, sh, wget

I have this wget command :

```
wget -P /home/storyplayr/storyplayr-web-playr -O sitemap.xml https://preprod.storyplayr.com/sitemap.xml?snapshots=true&onlyBlog=true --no-check-certificate
```

When executed from the command line, it works fine

When executed from a shell script (.sh), I have a 504 Getaway Time-out

I have tried to set up the time out on the wget command but it does nothing. It is clearly related to the sh command...

Any idea why ? Any idea on how to avoid this ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Have you checked in a normal browser call?

Comment: It works in a normal browser call. The issue is clearly not on the server side. It seems to me this is a sh related issue since it works with the command line.

Comment: It's possible that the server is reacting differently depending on what user agent you supply.